# Elasticclient - after two minutes longer response time

Tags: nest

I hope somebody can help.

I'm using the elasticclient where I set the connection uri to a pc on network e.g.: pcname.domain.com:port.

When I use the client first time, the response will be around 5 sec. Second time same request takes ~400 milisec.

Once I do not use the client for about 2 minutes it will again take 5 sec. Is there any settings what I can set to avoid this "5 sec" behaviour as much as possible?

In case of I use localhost the same request of 5 sec will be 200 milisec, when i use second time, less than 100 milisec.

Can somebody help pls? I checked the documentation as well as the source code, unfortunately I did not find the root cause.

Comment: Are you using a single instance of the client for the lifetime of the application? If not, it's recommended that you do, as the client generates code and caches data on initial usage. Where is the 5 seconds of time being spent - based on the info provided, it sounds like a lot of the latency is coming from the network

Comment: I save one client for lifetime, the first request takes several seconds then a few miliseconds.  If I do not touch the client for about two minutes it will again take that higher load time. I'm looking for a root cause for that two minutes usecase if I can extend.

Is it related to some dns? is it related to deadtime? or what?:)

Comment: I think the only way to know this is to measure in your environment. You could hook up an EventListener to capture DNS and related events e.g. https://gist.github.com/russcam/649a7d487cd6752b6e44dc196b97b52e